# CSS dropdown navbar design error

Tags: html, css

I have this list element in my navigation bar that I want to fix.

[image: Fixing the dropdown align and color]

HTML Code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn" style="cursor:allowed;">
    <b><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['nom']; ?> 
    </b>
    </a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="administration.php"><b>Administration</b></a></li></br>
           <li><a href="./traitement/deconnecter.php"><b>Deconneter</b></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</li>
```

CSS code:

```
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #669900 ;
}

li.dropdown 
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #555}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:inline-table;
}
```

My questions are: **how do I align the dropdown content to the center so it fits with the page? And how do I make the hover color on the dropdown content apply on the whole background instead of just the background of the name?**

Comment: "fix this" .. but...,uhm... how are we to know what it's *supposed* to look like??? Content to center of what? the menu title or the page? or center the items within the drop down? and "whole background" of what? The entire menu, just the drop down menu, the menu item?

Comment: @Scott It's self explinatory. I'm talking about the dropdown content(I already stated that, in case you didnt read the whole thing). The dropdown content hover applies on the element background only, not the entire dropdown background

Answer (score 1):

I changed one bit of code.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display:inline-table;
right:0px;}
```

This keeps the submenus from bleeding off the screen. You can alter the `px` value to shift it one way or the other.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Le7se5L9/

If your menus are generated dynamically, you may have to apply a different class to the last menu in the loop, or else all your menus may be shifted right a little.